# If $KerT$ is a subset of $Sp\{(1,0,1), (0,1,0)\}$ then $T(1,0,1)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it correct that if $Ker(T) \subseteq Sp\{(1,0,1), (0,1,0)\}$

Then $T(1,0,1) = 0$
and $T(0,1,0)=0$?

Or is the only thing that one can be sure of is that $T(\lambda_1(1,0,1) + \lambda_2(0,1,0))=0$ for some $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in F$

Comment: It is not. After all, $T$ may have a trivial kernel ($\ker T=\{0\}$) which is certainly contained in the span, but it does not contain *those two vectors*. so $T$ applied to them won't be zero. For the second question, you can also be sure that, if $T(v)=0$ then $v=\lambda_1(1,0,1)+\lambda_2(0,1,0)$ for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in F$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop and what about cases where $Ker(T) >= 1$?

Comment: Do you mean $\text{Nullity}(T)\geq 1$?  The kernel may be of *dimension* greater than or equal to $1$, but the kernel itself is a space and not a number and is as such incomparable to $1$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I meant $\dim{Ker(T)} >= 1$

Comment: Still none of those two vectors need to be in the kernel. Imagine $\ker T=\text{span}\{(1,1,1)\}\subset\text{span}\{(1,0,1),(0,1,0)\}$. Then $T$ will map vectors of the form $\lambda(1,1,1)$ to zero but won't map either of $(1,0,1),(0,1,0)$ to zero.

Comment: What does $(1,0,1),(0,1,0)$ or the span of them have anything to do with $T$?  This is like asking "If I eat toast tomorrow morning, does that mean anything with regards to how $T$ acts on these vectors?"  Do you mean for $\text{span}(\{(1,0,1),(0,1,0)\})$ to be the range of $T$ perhaps?

Comment: I believe the OP may be confusing the conditions $\ker T\subseteq\text{span}\{\ldots\}$ and $\ker T\supseteq\text{span}\{\ldots\}$. The second condition *would* guarantee that $(1,0,1),(0,1,0)\in\ker T$, i.e. $T(1,0,1)=T(0,1,0)=0$.